Unable to understand why my program is using too much RAM
EDIT2:
TL;DR Version
The following piece of code is causing huge memory burden. Library: Paruqet.NET
using (ParquetReader reader = await ParquetReader.CreateAsync(filePath, null))
{
    string tableName = GetTableName(filePath);
    Table parquetTable = await reader.ReadAsTableAsync(); //Main culprit for huge RAM consumption
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    string sql = $"CREATE TABLE {tableName} (";
    foreach(Field field in parquetTable.Schema.Fields)
    {

        DataField? ptField = field as DataField;
        string columnName = ptField.Name;
        Type columnType = ptField.ClrType;
        dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName, columnType);
        sql += $"[{columnName}] {GetSqlDataType(columnType, field)},";
    }

I am currently looking for any experts who can tell how I can read a paruqet file without overburdening RAM and dump the parquet data to SQL.
Complete Story
To give an overview of my project, I am writing a C# program that reads Parquet files, copies to a DataTable and then makes an SQL connection and using SqlBulkCopy dumps the data to an SQL server (SQL Server 2019, localdb located on the same machine).
I am using paralling processing, but I have to mention that I am new to C# as well parallel computing. Most of the code I have built here was by using ChatGPT and Googling.
Now, my program is going to read a directory, gather all files with extension ".parquet" and store them in a string array.
string[] fileList = GetParquetFiles(activeDirectory[0]);

These files will be read in parallel and I am using SemaphoreSlim to limit the number of active parallel threads.
public static async Task ProcessParquetFileAsync(string[] fileList, string databaseName)
{
    int numberOfConcurrentFiles = 2;
    using (SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(numberOfConcurrentFiles))
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var file in fileList)
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await ReadAndDeployParquetFile(file, databaseName);
                }
                finally
                {
                    semaphore.Release();
                }
            }));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    
}

Let's take a flow of 1 such thread.
Inside this thread, I am reading the whole Parquet file as a Table (I am using Parquet.NET library to read).
In each thread, I am reading the ParquetTable completely and copying the schema to a DataTable (Just the schema, no data).
Next, I am calculating batchSize to split and read the ParquetTable into "chunks".
These chunks of data are again processed parallelly using SemaphoreSlim
public static async Task ReadAndDeployParquetFile(string filePath, string databasename)
{
    using (ParquetReader reader = await ParquetReader.CreateAsync(filePath, null))
    {
        string tableName = GetTableName(filePath);
        Table parquetTable = await reader.ReadAsTableAsync();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        string sql = $"CREATE TABLE {tableName} (";
        foreach(Field field in parquetTable.Schema.Fields)
        {

            DataField? ptField = field as DataField;
            string columnName = ptField.Name;
            Type columnType = ptField.ClrType;
            dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName, columnType);
            sql += $"[{columnName}] {GetSqlDataType(columnType, field)},";
        }
        sql = sql.Trim(',') + ')';
        SQLConnection conn = new SQLConnection();
        conn.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, tableName, databasename);

        int rowCount = parquetTable.Count;
        int batchSize = 100000;
        decimal parts = Decimal.Ceiling((decimal)rowCount / (decimal)batchSize);
        
        SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(Environment.ProcessorCount);
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        Console.WriteLine($"File {tableName} has total batch {(int)parts}");
        for (int i= 0; i < (int)parts; i++)
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            int currentPart = i;
            tasks.Add(Task.Run (() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    ProcessBatch(parquetTable, dataTable.Clone(), currentPart, batchSize, tableName, databasename);
                }
                finally
                {
                    semaphore.Release();
                }
            }));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        
        
    }
}

Finally, it is added row-by-row into a new DataTable called partTable that each sub thread is given (The schema of main DataTable is cloned and sent across).
public static void ProcessBatch(Table parquetTable, DataTable partTable, int currentPart, int batchSize, string tableName, string databaseName)
{
    SQLConnection conn = new SQLConnection();
    int columnCount = parquetTable.Schema.Fields.Count;
    for (int i = currentPart * batchSize; (i < ((currentPart + 1) * batchSize)) && (i < parquetTable.Count); i++)
    {
        var row = parquetTable[i];
        var dataRow = partTable.NewRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
        {
            if (row[j] != null)
            {
                dataRow[j] = row[j] ?? DBNull.Value;
            }
        }
        partTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }
    conn.InsertTable(tableName, partTable, databaseName, currentPart);
    partTable.Dispose();
}

Now the issue is, there is a parquet file which as 2 million rows. The chunk size I have given is 100k, so now it would make 10 batches and run them in parallel but keep only 8 threads active at a time (Environment.ProcessorCount is 8 in my PC) and run the remaining 2 when any of the 8 frees up (correct me if I am wrong here).
The file itself is 24MB, but the RAM usage is shooting up to 3GB! How?
My understanding of how the program works is
When 1 sub-thread is done, it should free up all it's memory. But it appears as if this is not happening.
I used dotMemory application to check the memory usage and the RAM consumption keeps going UP and never comes down at any point.

Can anyone help me understand why the memory is not clearing up after the sub-thread job is done and also help me fix the code to reduce RAM usage?
Again, I am very new to C# and even more new to parallel computing, so please go easy on explanation.
EDIT: Fixed batchSize variable number, had wrongly set as 10k instead of 100k.

parquet file which as 2 million rows because of that, DataTable is not a suitable solution for this case. As DataTable has a lot of overheads to build in-memory database, which would result in high memory usage for large amount of data.

if the file is in CSV format, use CSVHelper library, and build a model for each table schema, then refactor your code to read and build insert batches directly. Also, remove the CREATE TABLE sql from the code, and just create the table once in the database and reuse it.

@iSR5 Unfortunately, the file received is parquet only, no CSV files. So, if not DataTable, what else should I use that is also compatible with SqlBulkCopy object so that it can be bulk inserted into SQL server?

It seems you only need to read in batches, and insert each patch. So, you don't need DataTable, you only need a StringBuilder to build the sql command for each batch. this will help out link

Like instead of loading in DataTable, just build the string sql command and just execute that sql command?

EDIT: So, I just checked now, even if I don't use DataTable, just simply reading the ParquetTable is increasing RAM usage. My issue is not RAM going high after reading Parquet, my issue is when one Parquet is done, it should free up its space completely, but it's not. (or so I believe)

Measure memory usage in Visual Studio (C#, Visual Basic, C++, F#) and inspect the Managed types reports to see which types of object use a lot of RAM.

As a side note, are you aware that you are creating twice as many concurrent tasks as the cores of your machine? You have created nested parallelization, with DOP = 2 for the outer parallelization and DOP = Environment.ProcessorCount for the inner parallelization. The total degree of parallelism is these two DOPs multiplied.

Could you try reducing the degree of parallelism to 1, and see if the memory continues being leaked?

@TheodorZoulias First of all, thank you very much for going through my code, it was indeed a good catch on DOP being multiplied more than processor count. But unfortunately, the RAM usage is still high as usual (though the processing time was quick with DOP set as 1 now).
.NET platform I am targeting is .NET 8
SQL Server version is 2019, it is a localdb located on the same machine.

Since the memory leak is reproduced with DOP = 1, I would suggest to work into minimalizing the example by writing the shortest code possible that reproduces the problem. Currently the problem is lost inside a ton of code related to parallelization and throttling, which is irrelevant to the core issue.

As a side note, you could replace the task creation + throttling code with the .NET 6 API Parallel.ForEachAsync. It would result to less code, with better behavior regarding exceptions.

@TheodorZoulias it is this piece of code that is retaining in memory even after the thread's task is completed
Table parquetTable = await reader.ReadAsTableAsync();
I am not able to understand why the thread is not releasing memory of all the objects and variables that was defined inside it.
Also, I did not know about using .NET 6 API. I was in the mindset that "latest is the best" till now regarding any technology aspect.

​If you have found that the Table parquetTable = await reader.ReadAsTableAsync(); line is the culprit of the memory leak, I would suggest to edit the question and replace all the complex code with the minimal code that demonstrates the use of this line. The simpler is your code, the more likely is to receive focused answers.

@TheodorZoulias yes you are right. I have now edited my question and included TL;DR version on top of the question narrowing the code segment which is causing the issue.


I used dotMemory

That's the only pertinent thing in your entire question, using a memory profiler to fix your problems. There's also one built into VS itself, you can find it in Debug > Performance Profile > Memory Profile.
However you didn't focus on the important part: what's rooting your objects. Rooting in .Net means objects that are directly stored as fields in classes that are forced to never be cleaned up. Their fields and their fields' fields and so on recursively keeps everything alive for as long as needed.
So if you ever have a question as to what's keeping things in memory (which is your entire question), follow that instance's references up to its root and you'll find out exactly what's not getting cleaned up and why.

Okay, so I did do some digging into my code and found out that. There is this one particular object that doesn't seem to get clear from memory even after it is done.
Table parquetTable = await reader.ReadAsTableAsync();
Basically, when 1 file is read, and completed loading into SQL, this parquetTable should clear and release all memory. But that is not happening so. I am not able to understand why not?
Once the thread is done and completes its task, shouldn't it release all the variable and objects that was defined in it?

There some metrics that you should consider:

use Release and publish in order to measure your RAM usage.
2)use string builder instead of string[] for big string arrays and when you want add sth.
set null for values after you do not need them, this will help GC.
In some case that you use event handler and delegates ensure that when you do not want to work with them unregister them or check that do not register that event multiple times.
use using for classes which inherited IDisposable


Out of the 4, I feel point 3 does not apply to my program as there are no event handlers.
Point 4 is already implemented to wherever I can.
I implemented 1 and 2, though there was improvement in a VERRRYY minimal way (like 50MB reduced), still usage is pretty high.

@SreenathHS On visual studio> Debug> Performance Profil Check the Object allocation tracking  and memory usage, At the end of the test it will show you which modules are using the memory too much.

Okay, I did try this out. But at the end, I do the see Process Memory going up (same as how it was in dotMemory), but underneath this graph is a title "View Heap", and inside it is a table with columns ID, Time, Objects, Heap Size, Label.
But this table is completely empty...

Point 2 is not good practice: Setting Objects to Null/Nothing after use in .NET.
